# Find integer that appears exactly once in array of unsorted integers in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I have been given an unsorted array of integers where each integer appears precisely twice, excluding one integer which appears only one time. 
I would like to write a program in Java that finds the integer that appears only once.

Here is my attempt:

```
int findIntegerThatOccursOnce(int[] arr)
{
    HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    int mSum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
        if(hashSet.contains(arr[i]))
        {
          mSum = mSum - arr[i];
        }
        else
        {
          hashSet.add(arr[i]);
          mSum = mSum + arr[i];
        }
    }
    return mSum;
}
```

My professor said it was a good attempt but there is a better one that uses less space but I cannot see how I can do it with less space? Can anyone help explain about the space issue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is working code and asking for a code review. So it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please read [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I want to know why my solution is bad regarding space I updated my question

Comment: @JarrodRoberson I don't agree that this is off topic; the OP is asking about a specific problem with the code (it uses too much space), so it's on topic on both sites IMHO

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the assertion that all numbers appear twice, *except* for one value you can xor all of the values and return the result. Like,

```
static int findIntegerThatOccursOnce(int[] arr) {
    int v = 0;
    for (int i : arr) {
        v ^= i;
    }
    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt takes **O(n)** time and **O(n)** space and is really quite good as there are a lot of simpler trivial solutions that are “worse” in both time and space.

One possible solution which could take less space could be if you used [Exclusive or (XOR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exclusive_or) on all the integers in the array; as all the integers that occur twice would cancel.

This would leave you with the one integer that only appears once. This solution would use **O(1)** space.